# URL redirect/rewrite using the .htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, url, redirect, url-rewriting

I have a issue with google indexing. 
The problem is that google indexed all my pages like `xx.com/ilan.php?ilan=test`
and also indexed like `xx.com/test.html`
But I want google to index my pages like `xx.com/test.html`

I have created a .htaccess and inserted into the above code

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule (.*)\.html$ ilan.php?ilan=$1
```

Question is How can get rid of this issue ? I would like to use 301 but I couldn't find the solution.

Answer (score 0):

Add `[R=301]` to `RewriteRule`

```
RewriteRule (.*)\.html$ ilan.php?ilan=$1 [R=301]
```

Comment: When I make like this, all url's redirecting to ilan.php?ilan=

Comment: it should be upend